# can I define a java interface in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I would like to define a java interface, in clojure - (as well as implement it) - I understand implementing can be done via both proxy and gen-class, but that always assumed the interface was already defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate a Java interface with both [`clojure.core/definterface`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/definterface) and [`clojure.core/gen-interface`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/gen-interface). (`definterface` expands to a call to `gen-interface`.)

```
(ns demo.api)

(definterface Store
  (^demo.api.Store buy [])
  (^demo.api.Store buy [^int q])
  (^demo.api.Store sell [])
  (^int getQty []))

;; or

(gen-interface
 :name demo.api.Store
 :methods [[buy [] demo.api.Store]
           [buy [int] demo.api.Store]
           [sell [] demo.api.Store]
           [getQty [] int]])
```

*Sampled from this [blog post](http://david-mcneil.com/post/691347818/wrapping-clojure-in-a-java-api)*.

If you want an "Interface", in the generic sense, then take a look at [Clojure Protocols](http://clojure.org/protocols).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, with [`definterface`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/definterface):

```
 (definterface MyInterface
  (^int method1 [x])
  (^Bar method2 [^Baz b ^Quux q]))
```

Unlike in some of the examples of the link above though, you can now type hint `^ints`, `^doubles` etc. in Clojure.

However be aware that there is currently no way to `docstring` the `definterface`.

Unless you have a need for Java compatibility though, you should look into clojure [`protocols`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defprotocol)

If this is about exposing Clojure code to Java it seems the best approach is to write the interface in Java and implement it in Clojure as seen in https://github.com/puredanger/clojure-from-java.